# A jar of mixed coins

Tags: probability, coin-tossing

This is a slight adaptation of a google interview question that I found entertaining.

You are given a jar with **N** coins, **K** of them are fair. The remaining coins have heads on both sides. You choose a coin at random from the jar and flip it **m** times.

1. If you get heads all **m** times, what is the probability that you selected a fair coin?
2. If **m** is 3, and **N** is 100, how many fair coins would need to be in the jar, for you to be at least 50% sure you selected a fair coin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability is given by $P(fair|heads^m) = P(heads^m|fair) \cdot P(fair) / P(heads^m)$, where

$P(heads^m) = P(heads^m|fair)\cdot P(fair) + P(heads^m|nonfair)\cdot P(nonfair) = 1/2^m \cdot K/N + 1^m \cdot (N-K)/N$.

Hence,

$P_m = \frac{1/2^m \cdot K/N}{1/2^m \cdot K/N + 1^m \cdot (N-K)/N)} .$

Solving for $K$, we find that it must be 88.8.

Comment: There are two questions. I presume your answer is for the first one and is expressed in %?

Comment: @ErikE, if you insert the numerical $m$ and $N$ into the formula for $P_m$ and set $P_m = 0.5$, you will have one unknown variable $K$. By solving this equation you get $K=88.8$, which answers the second question, right?

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, but do you see the problem with an answer "88.8 coins"?

Comment: I agree, the solution was correct, but I would have liked to see the answer 89 coins. (:

Comment: Alright, I agree an integer solution would be more proper.

Comment: 88.8 isn't "less proper", it's incorrect. :) but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> P(fair-coin|m-heads) = p(fair-coin & m heads)/p(m-heads)
>     p(fair-coin & m-heads) = K/N * (0.5^m)
>     p(m-heads) = p(m-heads & (fair-coin |unfair-coin)) = p(m-heads * fair-coin)+ p(m-heads *unfair-coin)
>     p(m-heads * unfair-coin) = p(unfair-coin)*p(m-heads/unfair-coin) = N-K/N

so answer to the first part = K/N * (0.5^m)/(K/N*(0.5^m)) + (N-K)/N)